# Looking for a good floating lable implementation that works with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know of a good floating label implementation that will work with Bootstrap on all browsers. I found one from Material Design (code below), but I would like the textbox to have a border and the placeholder to transition into something like a fieldset's legend. Any implementation that works on all browsers would be appreciated.

Here is the Material Design stuff:

```
    .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-control-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.form-control:focus + .form-control-placeholder,
.form-control:valid + .form-control-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

    <div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required>
        <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="name">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
        <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="password">Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 documentation has an example of Floating Labels, but it is considered an 'Experiment'

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/floating-labels/

Not quite 'all browsers' but specifically says 'Works in latest Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.'

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this, but it doesn't transition to a legend type label and I haven't tried it on mobile devices, At  any rate, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an input floating label for Bootstrap 4 & 5: https://github.com/tkrotoff/bootstrap-floating-label

[image: @tkrotoff/bootstrap-floating-label demo]

Here is the online demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tkrotoff/bootstrap-floating-label/tree/codesandbox.io